# Unable to pass form via FormData and XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
strURL = 'Somedomain.com/someurl.asp';
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open('POST',strURL,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

var TempForm = document.getElementById('frmTestInformation');
var TempData = new FormData(TempForm);

xmlhttp.send(TempData); 

var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
var myData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DATA");
```

Okay, the above code doesn't seem to be working for me.  Well, not entirely anyways.  The idea is that the form (frmTestInformation) will be passed to someurl.asp (obviously not the real URL).  The call is indeed being made and the responseXML returns a valid XML document.  However, by reading that document it's evident that the someurl.asp page did not receive any form data.  Am I doing something wrong in the passing of the information?  The form name is correct (I've checked it a bunch of times).  The receiving page is also correct.  I altered the form submission to submit directly to the page without going through JavaScript and everything worked fine.  Starting to pull my hair out over here.

Comment: Try removing the setRequestHeader call, I believe XHR automatically sets the correct content-type etc headers when using formdata

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem.  I only added that line to see if it would help.  I took it back out and it still doesn't. work.  :/